# Parsing String elements between nested parentheses

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a little program that extracts information from between nested parentheses. For example, if I'm given the string:

`"content (content1 (content2, content3) content4 (content5 (content6, content7))"`

I would like this to be returned (in an ArrayList or other Collection):

```
["content", "content1", "content2, content3", "content4", "content5", "content6, content7"]
```

Are there any already existing libraries or an algorithm that I could use to assist me in this.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Thanks for the suggestions however content2 and content3 should be saved in the same string in the final list because they are within the same set of parentheses.

Comment: So you do not care for the parantheses at all?

Comment: This regular expression seems to do what you want: [`\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*`](http://ideone.com/nm7eZj)

Comment: No I don't, the ordering in which they content appears within the parentheses matters and I'll handle that case once I figure out how to do the proper parsing

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in your example ( 4 left, 3 right) - is that a correct example?

Comment: Why not just [`[^)(]+`](https://regex101.com/r/cDsbTC/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to meet your one example given above:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class ParseParenthesizedString {
    public enum States { STARTING, TOKEN, BETWEEN }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ParseParenthesizedString theApp = new ParseParenthesizedString();
        theApp.Answer();
    }

    public void Answer()
    {
        String theString = 
           "content (content1 (content2, content3) content4 (content5 (content6, content7))";
        // wants:
        // ["content", "content1", "content2, content3", "content4", "content5", "content6, content7"]
        States state = States.STARTING;
        ArrayList<String> theStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer("");

        for (int i = 0; i < theString.length() ; i++)
        {
            char cTemp = theString.charAt(i);
            switch (cTemp)
            {
                case '(':
                {
                    if (state == States.STARTING)  state = States.BETWEEN;
                    else if (state == States.BETWEEN)  {} 
                    else if (state == States.TOKEN )
                    {
                        state = States.BETWEEN;
                        theStrings.add(temp.toString().trim());
                        temp.delete(0,temp.length());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ')':
                {
                    if (state == States.STARTING) 
                    {  /* this is an error */ }
                    else if (state == States.TOKEN) 
                    {
                        theStrings.add(temp.toString().trim());
                        temp.delete(0,temp.length());
                        state = States.BETWEEN;
                    } 
                    else if (state == States.BETWEEN ) {}
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    state = States.TOKEN;
                    temp.append(cTemp);
                }
            }
        }

        PrintArrayList(theStrings);
    }
    public static void PrintArrayList(ArrayList<String> theList)
    {    
        System.out.println("The ArrayList with " 
                + theList.size() + " elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ":" + theList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
The ArrayList with 6 elements:
0:content
1:content1
2:content2, content3
3:content4
4:content5
5:content6, content7
```

Comment: Cool. Do you happen to know functional program (Clojure for specific)? Since there're no states in functional program, how do you keep the states? I tried to recursively parse when '(' is found but then once I exit the recursive stacks (when ')' are found), I'm back all the way to the beginning of the first '('

Answer (score -1):

Java's String.split() will do the job for you. It requires a regex to define the delimiter between each token...for you, it seems your delimiters are parentheses or commas, optionally surrounded by whitespace on either side. So this should do the trick:

```
String[] result = s.split("\\s*[\\(\\),]+\\s*");
```

Comment: This works but it separates content2 from content3 and content6 from content7. These pairs are supposed to be part of the same resulting string.